# Error returned by ListAvailabilityDomains operation in Identity service.(-1, null, false) Unknown error Using OCI SDK Java

Tags: java, authentication, sdk, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Java code

```
`// Set up authentication details with hardcoded values
                SimpleAuthenticationDetailsProvider authProvider = SimpleAuthenticationDetailsProvider.builder()
                        .tenantId(tenantId)
                        .userId(accountId)
                        .fingerprint(accessKeyId)
                        .privateKeySupplier(new SimplePrivateKeySupplier(file.getLocation()))
                        .region(Region.valueOf(location.toUpperCase()))
                        .build();
                // Create an Identity client
                Identity identityClient = new IdentityClient(authProvider);

                // Make a simple API call to list availability domains
                ListAvailabilityDomainsResponse response =
                        identityClient.listAvailabilityDomains(
                                ListAvailabilityDomainsRequest.builder()
                                        .compartmentId(tenantId)
                                        .build());

                if (response.getItems() != null && !response.getItems().isEmpty()) {
                    logger.debug("Credentials are valid.");
                } else {
                    logger.debug("Credentials are invalid.");
                }`
```

Dependencies

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.oci.sdk/oci-java-sdk-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.oci.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>oci-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.23.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.oci.sdk/oci-java-sdk-identity -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.oci.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>oci-java-sdk-identity</artifactId>
            <version>3.23.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.oci.sdk/oci-java-sdk-common-httpclient-jersey -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.oci.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>oci-java-sdk-common-httpclient-jersey</artifactId>
            <version>3.23.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jersey Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version> <!-- Use the latest version -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jersey Jackson Support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version> <!-- Use the same version as jersey-server -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.ws.rs/jakarta.ws.rs-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Im getting
ERROR THAT IM GETTING IS
Error returned by ListAvailabilityDomains operation in Identity service.(-1, null, false) Unknown error
Timestamp: 2023-08-29T11:53:40.327Z
Client version: Oracle-JavaSDK/3.23.2
Request Endpoint: https://identity.eu-frankfurt-1.oci.oraclecloud.com/20160918/availabilityDomains?compartmentId=
Troubleshooting Tips: See https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/References/apierrors.htm#apierrors_-1__-1_ for more information about resolving this error.
i even tried to authenticate using other methods which uses listRegions() or the one that uses listInstances() but they are also giving same error